# How do I examine the health of the current connection pool in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Is there a ***command line*** utility or something I can run that will show me the status of each of the connections in the connection pool being managed by mysqld?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `show processlist` query to show all active connections on the server.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-processlist.html